# Grouping multiple columns in a view result for a report

Tags: views, entities

I have a requirement in which I need to display the stock report for an application as in the below image

[image]

I want to know how to group the Quantity, Batch no and Expiry date fields together in another column (Opening Stock) in Views. I am using Drupal 7 and Views 3.

Also I need a summary of the quantity in the footer of the view, for example sum of all quantity for a batch in the footer. Any help from the community is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

To group the quantity, Batch no and expiry date fields in another column, use the [views secondary row module](https://drupal.org/project/views_secondary_row)

> Provides a way to split a views table row into two. In the table style
>   settings, select a "Secondary row" option.
>
> So if a table looks like this: Name | Description | Edit link | Delete
>   link selecting "Name" as the secondary row option for "Edit link" and
>   "Description" as the secondary row option for the "Delete link" will
>   render two rows:

For summary of the quantity in the footer, use [Views summarize](https://drupal.org/project/views_summarize)

> Enables an extra display style which displays summaries of a column on
>   the last row.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but I want the column headers to be split and not the rows, the views secondary module will not be suitable for my scenario I guess, is there any other way I can use it or can I achieve it using custom code? It is just a display alteration and nothing to do with views processing of data. Views summarize seems to solve my problem to show summary results..thanks for that

Comment: How about creating your table normally and under advanced, on the theme information, select style output and create a custom tpl.php file, and then rewrite the table header in the .tpl.php file

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about it, I think it should work.